# Attaching multiple schemas to same collection using autoform and collection2

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have two forms and two schema that don't have anything in common. But I still need them to be stored in the same collection.

Eg.:

```
schema1 = new SimpleSchema({ field1, field2, field3 });
collection.attachSchema(schema1);

schema2 = new SimpleSchema({ fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ });
collection.attachSchema(schema2);
```

From [Collection2 documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/blob/master/README.md#attaching-multiple-schemas-to-the-same-collection) it is understood that the above method will actually merge both the schema into a single big schema. This means that both form must have all fields belonging to both schema.

This means that I can't have an autoForm with just schema1 and another autoform with just schema2.

As per the documentation, I tried implementing replace: true - by which, the schema gets overwritten each time. ( At least this is how I understand it - they don't get merged into a big schema)

Eg:

```
schema1 = new SimpleSchema({ field1, field2, field3 });
collection.attachSchema(schema1, {replace: true});

schema2 = new SimpleSchema({ fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ });
collection.attachSchema(schema2 {replace: true});
```

The above still does not fix the issue and Somehow, the schemas still get merged. Meaning, I still get notified that FieldX is blank in autoform1 even though there is no provision for fieldX to be filled.

I Also tried the other approach where in you use variations.

Eg.:

```
schema1 = new SimpleSchema({ field1, field2, field3 });
collection.attachSchema(schema1, {selector: {type: 'forForm1'}});

schema2 = new SimpleSchema({ fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ });
collection.attachSchema(schema2, {selector: {type: 'forForm2'}});
```

When I implement the above, I get an autoform error saying that an argument to doc must be passed when dealing with multiple schema.

How exactly do I do this?

THe documentation specifically states :

> Now both schemas are attached. When you insert a document where type:
>   'simple' in the document, it will validate against only the
>   SimpleProductSchema. When you insert a document where type: 'variant'
>   in the document, it will validate against only the
>   VariantProductSchema.

I Don't know how I need to pass doc = ???? in the template. Could someone guide me?

This is my autoform template:

**Form1:**

```
{{#autoForm    collection = "pgTemplates"  type ="insert" doc= ???? id ="InsertForm1" }}
{{#each afFieldNames}}
{{> afQuickField name=this.name options = afOptionsFromSchema  }}
{{/each}}
```

**Form2:**

```
{{#autoForm    collection = "pgTemplates"  type ="insert" doc= ???? id ="InsertForm1" }}
{{#each afFieldNames}}
{{> afQuickField name=this.name options = afOptionsFromSchema  }}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#autoform-1) for autoform:

> `doc`: Required for an update form, and must have at least an `_id`
>   property. Pass the current document object, retrieved with a call to
>   `findOne()` for example. For an insert form, you can also use this
>   attribute to pass an object that has default form values set (the same
>   effect as setting a value attribute on each field within the form).

There is also another parameter `schema` that may be of use in this case:

> `schema`: Required if collection is not set. This schema will be used to
>   generate and validate the form prior to submission, so you can specify
>   this along with a collection if you want to use a schema that is
>   slightly different from the one your collection uses. However, the
>   final object will still have to pass validation against the collection
>   schema. Set to one of the following:
>
> - The name of a helper function (no quotation marks) that returns an    instance of SimpleSchema.
> - The name (in quotation marks) of a    SimpleSchema instance that is in the window namespace.

So you can try setting the schema parameter according to your specific `schema` in each case, and also try to pass the current document object in `doc`.

I suppose the template would look like:

**Form1:**

```
{{#autoForm  collection = "pgTemplates"  schema="schema1"  type ="insert" doc=docObject id ="InsertForm1" }}
  {{#each afFieldNames}}
    {{> afQuickField name=this.name options = afOptionsFromSchema1  }}
  {{/each}}
```

**Form2:**

```
{{#autoForm  collection = "pgTemplates"  schema="schema2"  type ="insert" doc=docObject id ="InsertForm1" }}
  {{#each afFieldNames}}
    {{> afQuickField name=this.name options = afOptionsFromSchema2  }}
  {{/each}}
```

In the above case, you will need to make sure that your `schema` instances are available properly in the window namespace

Or you can have a helper function returning the specific instance, like:

**With helper:**

```
{{#autoForm  collection = "pgTemplates"  schema=getSchema1  type ="insert" doc=docObject id ="InsertForm1" }}
    {{#each afFieldNames}}
      {{> afQuickField name=this.name options = afOptionsFromSchema2  }}
    {{/each}}
```